# C# DirectShow .Net Centre video with background

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I am using DirectShow .NET to display video in a control in a C# form. I require to have the video to fill the control when the form and thus control is made bigger/smaller (the if branch of MainForm_ResizeMove handles this). I also require to maintain the source video size if a property is set. The code in the else section of MainForm_ResizeMove handles this. The problem I have is while the else section positons my video in the correct postion centered on the control, the background is grey. As I have set the video position to the size of the video then the border colour is not applied (as there is no border in this case). Can someone advise what the best solution would be?

```
private IVMRWindowlessControl9 windowlessCtrl = null;

...
private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {           
        if (windowlessCtrl != null)
        {
            IntPtr hdc = e.Graphics.GetHdc();
            int hr = windowlessCtrl.SetBorderColor(0x00FFFFFF);
            hr = windowlessCtrl.RepaintVideo(this.Handle, hdc);
            e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
        }
    }

    private void MainForm_ResizeMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (windowlessCtrl != null)
        {
            if (fillScreen || (this.ClientRectangle.Width < streamFrameWidth) || (this.ClientRectangle.Height < streamFrameHeight))
            {
                int hr = windowlessCtrl.SetVideoPosition(null, DsRect.FromRectangle(this.ClientRectangle));
            }
            else
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((this.ClientRectangle.Width / 2) - (streamFrameWidth / 2), 
                                               (this.ClientRectangle.Height/ 2) - (streamFrameHeight / 2), 
                                                streamFrameWidth, streamFrameHeight);
                int hr = windowlessCtrl.SetVideoPosition(null, rect);  
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was infact simple, set the background colour of the control to black!!